# Circular transformation in dec (C)

Tags: c

I have to make a program that reads 2 integers without 0 in their digits and it says if the 2nd is made of circular transformation of the first. ex: 4123,3412,2341 and 1234 are made of circular transformation of 1234. Now here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
int last_digit, a, temp, i, b;
int digits = 0, digits1 = 0;

printf("Enter two numbers to test if the second is a circular\n");
printf("transformation of the first.");
printf("\n\n**NOTE**\nThe numbers cannon have 0 in their digits.\n\na= ");
scanf("%d", &a);
while (a <= 0)
{
    printf("Number must be greater than 0.\na= ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
}
temp = a;
while (temp!=0)
{
    digits1++;
    temp/=10;
}
printf("b= ");
scanf("%d", &b);
while (b <= 0)
{
    printf("Number must be greater than 0.\nb= ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
}
while (digits != digits1)
{
    digits = 0;
    temp = b;
    while (temp!=0)
    {
        digits++;
        temp/=10;
    }
    if (digits != digits1)
    {
        printf("The two numbers must have the same number of digits.\nb= ");
        scanf("%d", &b);
    }
}
temp = b;
digits--;
for (i=1;i<=digits1;i++)
{
    if (temp == a)
    {
        printf("%d is a circular transformation of %d",b,a);
        return 0;
    }
    printf("\ntemp = %d",temp);
    last_digit = temp % 10;
    temp = temp/10;
    printf("\n%d\n%d",last_digit,temp);
    temp = temp + (last_digit*(pow(10,digits)));
    printf("\ntemp = %d\n",temp);
}
printf("%d is not a circular transformation of %d",b,a);
return 0;
}
```

Before you say anything i have to do it without using tables and other stuff... just the basics. Now my problem is that

```
temp = temp + (last_digit*(pow(10,digits)));
```

is not working as it should. If the number has more than 2 digits it gives me what it should - 1.

What can i do to fix this? Does it have to do with the compiler? I use GCC from code blocks.

if i do

```
temp = temp + (last_digit*(pow(10,digits))) + 1;
```

it works for numbers with more than 2 digits and not for numbers with 2 digits.

Comment: `pow()` has to do with floating-point stuff, so it's inherently inexact. Maybe `pow(10, 2)` is `99.9999` which is truncated to `99` when converted to an `int`. Don't use `pow()`. Use repeated (***integer!***) multiplication instead.

Comment: You can make a special case for `142857` =)  http://www.numberphile.com/videos/cyclic_numbers.html

Comment: You can use your decomposition loop to check that there are no zero digits in the number too: `while (temp != 0) { if (tmp % 10 == 0) fprintf(stderr, "Hey: no zero digits allowed!\n"; ... }`

Comment: The code as given works for me with GCC 4.8.2 on Mac OS X 10.9.  Tests with 1, 2, 3, 4, and 9 digits, mostly valid rotations, a couple of invalid rotations, all handled correctly.  Since `pow(10, digits)` is the same for every iteration of the loop, you could do an integer calculation of the value in a loop outside the loop: `int power_10 = 1; for (int i = 1; i < digits; i++) power_10 *= 10;` and then use `power_10` in place of `pow(10, digits)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot I solved it! It should be what @H2CO3 said. I used a for loop to calculate the pow(10,digits)!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Take into account that there's a chance OP is not using OS X, where `pow()` is implemented in a meaningful/mostly correct way for integers. :) If he's using Windows, that can't be said about the standard (<s>crap that comes outta Microsoft</s>) library.

Comment: @H2CO3: That's why I identified my platform carefully, and provided an alternative means of calculation, roughly as you advocated. It's also why I've only posted comments; you may/should post an answer; I'd probably even up-vote if I remember to look back (for example because you post a comment).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sure, I was not saying that your comment was inappropriate! It's just that *OP* didn't identify his platform/toolchain. I'm not posting an answer because... well, out of principle; I've written enough of these already. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef long Value;

#define SCN_Value "ld"
#define PRI_Value "ld"

static int num_digits(Value number)
{
    Value n0 = number;
    int r = 0;
    int ndigits = 0;
    while (number != 0)
    {
        ndigits++;
        if (number % 10 == 0 && r++ == 0)
            fprintf(stderr, "Number %" PRI_Value " should not have any zero digits\n", n0);
        number /= 10;
    }
    return ndigits++;
}

static Value prompt_for(char const *tag)
{
    Value number = -1;
    while (printf("%s = ", tag) > 0 &&
           scanf("%" SCN_Value, &number) == 1 &&
           number <= 0)
    {
        printf("Number (%" PRI_Value ") must be greater than 0.\n", number);
    }
    return number;
}

int main(void)
{
    Value num1, num2;

    printf("Enter two numbers to test if the second is a circular\n");
    printf("transformation of the first.\n");
    printf("**NOTE**\nThe numbers cannot have 0 as one of their digits.\n");

    if ((num1 = prompt_for("a")) < 0)
        return 1;
    int digits1 = num_digits(num1);

    if ((num2 = prompt_for("b")) < 0)
        return 1;

    while (digits1 != num_digits(num2))
    {
        printf("The two numbers must have the same number of digits.\n");
        if ((num2 = prompt_for("b")) < 0)
            return 1;
    }

    Value pow_10 = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < digits1; i++)
        pow_10 *= 10;

    Value temp = num2;
    for (int i = 1; i <= digits1; i++)
    {
        if (temp == num1)
        {
            printf("%" PRI_Value " is a circular transformation of %" PRI_Value "\n", num2, num1);
            return 0;
        }
        int last_digit = temp % 10;
        temp /= 10;
        temp = temp + last_digit * pow_10;
        printf("rotation = %" PRI_Value "\n", temp);
    }
    printf("%" PRI_Value " is not a circular transformation of %" PRI_Value "\n", num2, num1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Joathan Leffler When i try to run it in code blocks i get this error: 'for' loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode.
Note: use option -std=C99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code. How do i fix this?

Comment: Use `-std=c99` or `-std=gnu99` as one of the compiler options (where you put `-Wall` and the other warning options you use).  Or move the declaration out of the loop control, to the start of the enclosing block. In this case, add `int i;` at the top of the main function, and remove the `int` from `for (int i = 0;...`, twice. You may also have to worry about the definition of `digits1`, `pow_10`, `temp` and `last_digit`.